# Simple Rest to return Json using jersey

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

Hi I'm trying to return Json from a method in a simple rest using Jersey

**HelloWorldService.class**

```
  @Path("/hello")
    public class HelloWorldService {
        
        @GET
        @Path("/empdetail/{id}")
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public EmpDetailsVo getEmpDetails(@PathParam("id") String id){
            
            EmpDetailsVo details = new EmpDetailsVo();
            details.empId="1202";
            details.empName="Akhi";
            details.empAddress="123 Main St. Newark PA 19121";
            return details;
            
        }
    }
```

`EmpDetailsVo` class has getter and setters for `empId`, `name` and `address`.

When I try to run this url:

```
http://localhost:8080/jerseyRest/rest/hello/empdetail/1202
```

I get Http status `500`.

And on console I see an error:

```
SEVERE: A message body writer for Java class jerseyRest.EmpDetailsVo, and Java type class jerseyRest.EmpDetailsVo, and MIME media type application/json was not found
```

And

```
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class jerseyRest.EmpDetailsVo, and Java type class jerseyRest.EmpDetailsVo, and MIME media type application/json was not found
```

Can someone please help.

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell Jersey how to marshal and unmarshal objects from the `EmpDetailsVo` type into JSON.

Check [this tutorial](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/rest/jersey/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/) for an example of how this can be done.   Here's another example [using a different approach](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/json.html).   Investigate the use of the `com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature` parameter provided to your web application via web.xml, and that should get you there.